# Is it possible to get email analytics like the number of clicks on an email by writing custom code?

Tags: soap-api, analytics

I am volunteering for a non profit which would like to get analytics on their emails. Since they cannot afford pardot or marketing cloud, I am looking for options to provide the same function using custom code.

I have explored the [email message](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_emailmessage.htm) api but I cannot seem to find any calls that can be made to retrieve such info. Anyone with ideas on how to go about it?

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at [Salesforce Surveys](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/trails/get-started-with-salesforce-surveys), they provide tracking that might work for your use case.

Comment: That will not help I am afraid.

Comment: Visit the [Power of Us](https://www.salesforce.org/help/power-of-us-hub/) hub, they might have more ideas.